# Owin Context Username is blank

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, owin

I have following method which will be called in my web api

```
 public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
```

i need to set role as claim based if the username in the context.

But there is no value for context.username

I need to know where the username has been set.

Please see the full context

```
Writing context
ClientId:; UserName:; Password:; Scope:System.String[]; Ticket:; IsValidated:False; HasError:False; Error:; ErrorDescription:; ErrorUri:; OwinContext:Microsoft.Owin.OwinContext; Options:Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth.OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions; Request:Microsoft.Owin.OwinRequest; Response:Microsoft.Owin.OwinResponse; 

Writing Request
Environment:Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallEnvironment.AspNetDictionary; Context:Microsoft.Owin.OwinContext; Method:POST; Scheme:https; IsSecure:True; Host:holmesdev.nam.nsroot.net:4321; PathBase:/hisapi; Path:/token; QueryString:; Query:Microsoft.Owin.ReadableStringCollection; Uri:https://server.nam.nsroot.net:4321/hisapi/token; Protocol:HTTP/1.1; Headers:Microsoft.Owin.HeaderDictionary; Cookies:Microsoft.Owin.RequestCookieCollection; ContentType:application/x-www-form-urlencoded; CacheControl:; MediaType:; Accept:application/json, text/plain, */*; Body:Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallStreams.InputStream; CallCancelled:System.Threading.CancellationToken; LocalIpAddress:1XX.171.XX.XX5; LocalPort:4321; RemoteIpAddress:10.XX.XX3.XX1; RemotePort:591XX; User:; 

Writing Response
Environment:Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallEnvironment.AspNetDictionary; Context:Microsoft.Owin.OwinContext; StatusCode:200; ReasonPhrase:OK; Protocol:; Headers:Microsoft.Owin.HeaderDictionary; Cookies:Microsoft.Owin.ResponseCookieCollection; ContentLength:; ContentType:text/html; Expires:; ETag:; Body:Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb.CallStreams.OutputStream;
```

How to populate "username"?

Only place i get the value for userid is in the api controller. shown below:

```
 [Route("api/User/UpdateUserDetail")]
  [HttpPost]
  public HttpResponseMessage UpdateUserDetail(User userData)
```

There is no user name is available in SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider.cs , how should i bring userid from controller to SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider.